Mock a property to return another attribute
With this class:
class Something():
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name=name
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        # In real life, something long and complicated
        return "no"

I would like to mock it, by mocking .value to return .name instead.
In my test function, I have:
def side_effect(side_self:Something):
    return side_self.name

with patch.object(Something, "value", side_effect=side_effect, autospec=True):
    ...

Errors out because Something().value return a MagicMock, not the str (name) I expect.
If instead I patch with (Something, "value", new_callable=PropertyMock, side_effect=side_effect I get .side_effect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'side_self'
How can I mock value to return name?

Do you want to test Something, or mock it? Trying to do both is generally a smell.

Good point, and question edited. I want to mock, not test.

If you create a Mock(spec=Something) you'd be able to set its value attribute, and the fact that in the real implementation there's an underlying descriptor becomes irrelevant. How to do that depends on how whatever you're testing receives an instance of Something.

You may need to use PropertyMock https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock
